# How to make a excel export header with kendo UI Grid

Tags: kendo-ui

[How to add a header to excel using Kendo UI Grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gx891.png)

I am using Javascript and Jquery.

Comment: I need the header where it says " ADD NEW HEADER HERE" from the picture attached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a new row/rows to the beginning of your exported file and modify the cell attributes to style it in the format of your attached image.

You could use [`unshift`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_unshift.asp) to insert a row at the beginning of your `rows` array containing the header title.

And then use additional cell attributes to style the header title (like `textAlign` and `colSpan`).

```
var rows = e.workbook.sheets[0].rows;
rows.unshift({
    cells: [ { value: "My title", background: "#ff0000", colSpan: 2, textAlign: "right" } ]
});
```

[Dojo example](http://dojo.telerik.com/UPeZO) to demonstrate the above.

### EDIT

In order to modify the size of the font used in the header cell, you can use the [`fontSize`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ooxml/workbook#configuration-sheets.rows.cells.fontSize) attribute.

```
var rows = e.workbook.sheets[0].rows;
rows.unshift({
    cells: [ { value: "My title", fontSize: 20, background: "#ff0000", colSpan: 2, textAlign: "right" } ]
});
```

Comment: I need the Title Header alll the way at the top of the page, for example you have a header and you can have footers.

Comment: I need the header where it says " ADD NEW HEADER HERE" from the picture attached.

Comment: If you want to set the actual page header, this is not possible ([read designing reports considerations](http://docs.telerik.com/reporting/designing-reports-considerations-csv)). Page header and footer sections are ignored during processing. If you need headers and footers, consider using the PDF export instead, otherwise the above implementation would be as close as you are going to get unfortunately.

Comment: Ok. How do you make the font size larger with the code you have above?

Comment: Updated the question to include font size